# Calling NOW() function in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm using php for making queries for mysql. Here is one:

```
UPDATE `subscribers` SET `curDate` = NOW() WHERE `e_mail` = "$resEmail"
```

curDate - DateTime type. The problem is that after this query curDate of given email is

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

What's wrong?

Comment: show your `CREATE TABLE` statement so we can see datatypes.  Also, it's very bad practice to name fields with reserved words (like curDate- remember sql isn't case sensitive),

Comment: If you execute: select NOW(); What do you get from MySql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your PHP probably looks like this now:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE `subscribers` SET `curDate` = NOW() WHERE `e_mail` = "$resEmail"';
```

The single quotes prevent the variable's value from being substituted into the string. You will need to change it to this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `subscribers` SET `curDate` = NOW() WHERE `e_mail` = '$resEmail'";
```

You should also be aware that you may have an SQL injection vulnerability here. Consider using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escape the email address.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `subscribers` SET `curDate` = NOW() WHERE `e_mail` = '" .
       mysql_real_escape_string($resEmail) . "'";
```

Comment: Can I insert php-variables in single quotes?

Comment: @Ockonal: If the entire string is in double quotes, the single quotes inside that string don't prevent the php-variable from being interpreted.

Comment: "In MySQL strings must be surrounded by single quotes, not double quotes." - only true if the server mode `ANSI_QUOTES` is set, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html

Comment: @VolkerK: Sorry... you are right: +1, I removed that incorrect line. But the change I suggested should still work because the single quotes that I assume are there (but not included in the question) will prevent the variable from being substituted into the string in PHP. Swapping the single and double quotes should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using timedate function which is based on proper timestamp, try setting it with  `Timestamp(Now())`.